# Showing two spans are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let x,y,z be non-zero vectors and suppose $w=-2z\text{. Let }z=y-x$, so $w=-2y+2x$.
I have to check whether the following spans are equal:
a) span $(w,x,z)$=span($w,y$) and 
b) span($w,z$)=span($w,x,y$)

I did the following:
For a) (LHS): $span(w,x,z)=span(-2y+2x,x,y-x)=span(x,y)$
by linear combination.
(RHS): $span(w,y)=span(-2y+2x,y)=span(x,y)$
by linear combination.
so the spans are equal

b) (LHS):$span(w,z)=span(-2y+2x,y-x)=span(x,y)$.
(RHS): $span(w,x,y)=span(-2y+2x,x,y)=span(x,y)$.
so they're also equal.

However, the correct answer is that the spans in a) equal while the spans of b) do not equal.

Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong, and how I would determine if the spans are actually equal?

Comment: please use mathJax, otherwise it is rather difficult to read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

If $a \in \mbox{span}(w,z)$, then $a  = \alpha w+\beta z = -2 \alpha y+2 \alpha x + \beta y - \beta x = \alpha w+ \beta y + (-\beta)x \in \mbox{span}(w,x,y).   $

however $a = w+y+x \in \mbox{span}(w,x,y)$, and $a = w+y+x \notin \mbox{span}(w,z)$ ($y+x \neq z$ for example or study the equality of linear combinations). That is why spans of b) do not equal.